# Net Logo Turtle disappears inside of Patch

Tags: netlogo, patch

In Net Logo is there a value for a turtles Z coordinate, or its height in the 3D View? I have white patches in my simulation, when my turtles go into those patches they are not visible until they emerge from the other side of the patch.

In the screen shot, you can see edges of turtles inside of my white patches, I want to display them on top of the patch.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, simply use

```
set zcor 2
```

will place the turtles on top of the patches as I had hoped.

Comment: It may be interesting to look at the models library for the 3D examples